# Почему из #value первого поля в форме вырезаются пробелы?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Есть форма и кнопка выше нее. При нажатии на кнопку выводятся значения для первого и второго (нулевого и первого) полей - `email` и `username`.

```js
document.querySelector("#validate").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(document.querySelector("form").elements[0].value);
  console.log(document.querySelector("form").elements[1].value);
});
```

```html
<button id="validate">Validate Form!</button>
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <p><label for="email">Email</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p><label for="username">Username</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  </p>
  <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </p>
  <p><label for="password-conf">Password Confirmation</label></p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password-conf" id="password-conf">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="commit2" value="Submit2">
    <input type="submit" name="commit3" value="Submit3">
  </p>
</form>
```

Вопрос: почему, если ввести и в первое и во второе поля **пробелы**, то результат для первой строки - ничего, а для второй - эти введенные пробелы?

*Замечание:* даже если строка не содержит только пробелы, а начинается с пробелов, а заканчивается каким-нибудь набором символов, то пробелы из начала первой строки все равно исчезают.

Браузер - Chrome 58.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type="email"`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

> Any trailing and leading whitespace is removed from each address in
>   the list.
>
> Пробельные символы в начале и в конце каждого адреса автоматически удаляются.

Comment: "The <input> element's value attribute's value contains a DOMString which is automatically validated as conforming to email syntax.". Выходит, что novalidate на форме не играет роли?

Comment: И да, он там есть (у меня, не здесь в сниппете).

Comment: @smellyshovel это не проверял. Отвечаю на вопрос про пробелы.

Comment: Ну, судя по всему, выходит что novalidate только назойливые стандартные "алерты" отключает, но не это поведение. Что ж, спасибо. Вопрос, пожалуй, переформулирую, чтоб в поиске индексировался нормально.